# C# WPF. ListBox не обновляется

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Суть проблемы - ListBox внешне не обновляется при редактировании элемента...

Код ListBox'a:

```
<ListBox Name="ListBoxSyncItem" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Grid.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Изменить" Click="MenuItem_Update_OnClick"></MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem Header="Удалить" Click="MenuItem_Delet_OnClick"></MenuItem>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Grid.ContextMenu>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

В окне в DataContext прописывается ObservableCollection

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<ListBoxItemSync> _listBoxItemSyncs = new ObservableCollection<ListBoxItemSync>();
...
public MainWindow()
        {
...
ListBoxSyncItem.DataContext = _listBoxItemSyncs;
```

Код ListBoxItemSync:

```
private class ListBoxItemSync
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public SyncItem SyncItem { get; set; }
        }
```

Метод MenuItem_Update_OnClick (Вызывается через контекстное меню элемента ListBox'a):

```
private void MenuItem_Update_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var targetListItem = (ListBoxItemSync) ((MenuItem) sender).DataContext;
        var window = new CreateSyncItemWindow(targetListItem.SyncItem);
        //if (window.ShowDialog() == true)
        //{
        //  targetListItem.SyncItem = window.GetNewItem();
        //  targetListItem.Name = targetListItem.SyncItem.Name;
        //}

        if (window.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            _listBoxItemSyncs.Remove(targetListItem);
            _listBoxItemSyncs.Add(new ListBoxItemSync() {SyncItem = window.GetNewItem(), Name = window.GetNewItem().Name });
        }
    }
```

В CreateSyncItemWindow создается новый элемент SyncItem, возвращается через метод GetNewItem.

В закомментированном куске кода **нерабочий** вариант. Он обновляет данные в коллекции _listBoxItemSyncs (ее элементы должен отображать ListBox), но внешний вид ListBox'a не меняется.

Второй вариант (тот что не закомментирован) удалит старый элемент из коллекции и добавит новый. Это обновит внешний вид ListBox'a, но данный метод мне не нравится тем, что "обновленный" элемент появится в любом случае в конце списка, а искать номер старого элемента перед его удаление... В общим кода будет много.

Как быть с 1 вариантом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что ваш класс `ListBoxItemSync` не реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged`. И таким образом ваши контролы не могут узнать, что содержимое поменялось.

Делайте так:

```
class ListBoxItemSync : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { if (name != value) { name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
    }

    SyncItem syncItem;
    public SyncItem SyncItem
    {
        get { return syncItem; }
        set { if (syncItem != value) { syncItem = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
    }

    void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. _Изи же, и чего это я..._

Comment: @Opossum: Пожалуйста! Одна голова хорошо, а две лучше.